# How to extract human vocal from song with background music provided by librosa

Tags: python, audio, librosa

How to extract **human vocal** from song **with background music provided**  by librosa or else.
(e.g. I got two file `"SongName.mp3"`, `"SongName_bgm.mp3"`)

I searched the question and results told me to use *machine learning* (Instead of use background music).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the background music in the mixture (`SongName.mp3`) is exactly the same as in `SongName_bgm.mp3`, you can load the audio file and perform subtraction.

```
y_mix, _ = librosa.load("SongName.mp3", sr=None, mono=False)
y_bgm, _ = librosa.load("SongName_bgm.mp3", sr=None, mono=False)
y_vocal = y_mix - y_bgm

# now you can save this y_vocal into an audio file using `sndfile` or any audio utility.
```